# How pre-emption works?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, operating-system, kernel, scheduled-tasks

As per my understanding, schedulers do following items:

1. Calculate the time slice for the task(this could be algorithm dependent).
2. Switch Tasks - An ideal schedulers like to do in O(1). A good scheduling algorithm provides O(logN) complexity. Criteria to pick new task is again scheduling algorithm dependent.

My question is for pre-emptiom. For example a new task is created and it needs to run right away(and it does satisfies the condition - example it has higher priority than current running task).

How will scheduler know that a new task with higher priority is available and needed to run. We need to have some controlling code in Kernel implementation which detects such task entry and invokes Scheduler to save state of current running task and reschedule the new task. I would like to know more detail about such software entity.

Additionally I would expect this code to be scheduled to run on CPU to control "scheduler" and make scheduler switch task.

Please advise how this is implemented or may be I have some gaps in my understanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to understand this is to read a book like "The design of the X Operating System" where X is one of {Unix, Linux, BSD...}. You should find a chapter on Context Switches and a chapter on the Scheduler. You could also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29#Linux, but the book is probably better.

Basically, when user code does a system call (such as to create a new process, or to release a semaphore, or ...) or when you get a clock interrupt, or when you get some sort of other interrupt, the running state of the user process is always dumped out to memory so that kernel code can be run without messing up the user process. Once you have done this, the user process that was running isn't much different from any other runnable user process.

As part of the work required to service the system call, or interrupt, or whatever, the system can notice that there is a new runnable process or that some other process that was not runnable before is now runnable, and ask the scheduler to update its notion of the highest priority runnable process. It might also notice that a scheduling quantum has just expired, and ask the scheduler to run a complete reschedule.

Once the kernel code has done its stuff it will probably see that the scheduler has marked the highest priority runnable process, and the kernel code will read that process's state out of memory and return to it without worrying very much about whether it is the process that was running before the system call or whatever or not.

Exception: once upon a time machines worried about the cost of dumping and restoring floating point registers, which kernel mode didn't really need, because it could be written so that it never did floating point. In this case, the save/restore code might be written so that it didn't save the floating point registers unless it had to, and the kernel might check as part of the restore to see if it was switching to a new process, and needed to dump out and restore the floating point registers. For all I know, stuff might still do this, or there might be some more modern state that is only saved and restored when the process really is changing. But this is really just a detail in either case.

Comment: Your suggestion about book is what I too agree with. +1. And nice detailed answer of course.

Comment: Thanks for your expatiation. This makes sense to me. I will also read the book and articles suggested by you.